# Expanding disk space EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a windows server running on Amazon EC2, and I needed to expand the disk space available, so I followed this guide:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html

I changed from 30GB to 250GB, but when I now log in to the server using remote desktop, it still says that disk C is just 30GB. Am I forgetting something, or is it just not possible to increase the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll need to tell Windows to resize the volume. Exactly how you do it depends on the version of Windows you're running.  See [step 6 in these instructions](http://cloud.tekgoblin.com/2012/08/27/aws-guides-how-to-resize-a-ec2-windows-ebs-volume/) for an example of what you need to do.